# Passing a class using template

Tags: java, generics

I'm created a interface to abstract some common methods on 2 classes, here is the code

```
package br.canabarro.resource;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BaseResource<T, ID> {

    ResponseEntity save( T entity);

    ResponseEntity delete(ID id);

    ResponseEntity getAll();

    ResponseEntity getById(ID id);

    ResponseEntity update(ID id, T entity);
}
```

I'm have another file called ProductResource

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody DtoProduct productDTO) {
    final Product product = new Product(productDTO.getName());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(productService.save(product));
}
```

The `save` method are implementend on this function, but the compiler returns **Method does not override method from its superclass**, but if i change the function parameter to `Product productParam` will pass, the class `Product` have and `id` and `name` on the parameters.
The last part is my `ProductToDto` and this method also implement a interface called `SuperConverter`

```
package br.canabarro.dto.Conversor;

import br.canabarro.dto.DtoProduct;
import br.canabarro.entity.Category;
import br.canabarro.entity.Product;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class ProductToDto implements SuperConverter<Product, DtoProduct> {

    @Override
    public DtoProduct apply(Product product) {
        List<String> categoriesID = product
                .getCategories()
                .stream()
                .map(Category::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return DtoProduct
                .build()
                .id(product.getId())
                .name(product.getName())
                .builder();
    }
}
```

How can i change the `BaseResoucer` to make java understand what i want is passing a template `T` and not the class name like `DtoProduct`.
I'm sorry if the question became so long but this is a important question for me.
On the pastebin i'm posting my `SuperConverter` and the `DtoProduct`
`SuperConverter`: https://pastebin.com/TmFRLQVz
`DtoProduct`: https://pastebin.com/VTSnMVhq

Comment: where is `productService` defined?

Comment: Can i send to you the github project to make easily to understand?

Comment: The github with the full source https://github.com/jcanabarro/exercise-back-end maybe can you better understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProductResource is defined as:

```
public class ProductResource implements BaseResource<Product, String>
```

So Product becomes your T in BaseResource. In such case it is expected that ProductResource implements the following method:

```
ResponseEntity save(Product entity);
```

And it does not do that.

You would need to define your ProductResource as:

```
public class ProductResource implements BaseResource<DtoProduct, String>
```

or if you want to keep it as Product then implement the following method:

```
ResponseEntity save(Product entity);
```

It is not really Spring issue but Java generics. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Thanks Mateusz Mrozewski, was a simple error but i not pay much attention o this details, i'm sorry if i'm put wrong tags i will fix this.